# Can I run programs/CLI using a PWA?

Tags: javascript, progressive-web-apps

I heard PWA is capable of more things than a regular web app when it comes to client side operations.

As a disclaimer, I'd like to note that the PWA I've been working on is a privately used project, it has no malicious intent to harm any system.
What I want to do is I want to be able to use cec-client to turn the TV on/off on the system, so I want to be able to either run a pre-written bash script, or access CLI on the system. Is it somehow possible using a PWA? Currently the client system has a simple nodejs app that's listening to a call on localhost from the web app, which in turn turns the TV on. I want to change it to a more sophisticated solution, hence I'm wondering if PWA can run scripts on the client's system.

Comment: PWA can't run scripts. PWAs can't do much more than a normal website really except from few features

Comment: You could maybe have a backend LAN server running that can actually do those things, although you'd probably need it to use HTTPS which would be annoying to do. As far as I know, being able to share to a PWA is the only PWA exclusive feature, although there are many HTTPS exclusive features.

Comment: Or I guess electron might be an option since that would simplify connecting the backend and frontend

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The system that you are currently using (server side code with access to the necessary API) is likely the best method.

Progressive Web Apps are just websites with some extra features to persist state and emulate some functions available to system apps, and the security risks that would be involved if they could execute arbitrary system code would be enormous.